# Como hacer que Access se abra desde la linea de tares?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

He estado revisando el foro pero no consigo solucionar mi problema
Estoy usando Access 2013, en un formulario pulso un botón para verifican el spelling y la gramática de un campo. Para ello uso el verificador de Word. La verificación funciona correctamente. Pero una vez cerrado Word, Access queda en la barra de tareas parpadeando, y tengo que pulsar en el para que se abra y poder seguir trabajando. Quiero que Access se abra automáticamente.
He intentado activarlo usando Hwnd, SetForegroundWindow y otro montón de cosas que he visto en el foro, pero nada funciona.

El codigo es:

```
Private Sub Comando2_Click()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

accessid = GetCurrentProcessId
accesshwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With objWord
       Set doc = .Documents.Add
       .Selection.Text = Me.Texto0
       docum = doc & " - Word"
       .Visible = True
       VBA.AppActivate (docum)
       .Visible = False
       .Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
       If Len(.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
          Me.Texto0 = .Selection.Text
'          spellcancell = False
       Else
'          spellcancell = True
       End If
       doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    .Quit
End With

Set objWord = Nothing

AppActivate (accessid)
SetForegroundWindow accesshwnd


End Sub
```

Gracias por anticipado por vuestra ayuda
Saludos

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Haz clic en [edit] y  traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada.

Comment: perdon, lo cambio

Comment: Una aclaración importante: [es.so] NO es un *foro*, es un sitio de Preguntas y Respuestas (*Q&A)*, por lo tanto funciona diferente a como lo hace un *foro*, ya que aquí no debatimos o hacemos *hilos*, aquí respondemos preguntas bien formuladas. Hago esta acotación para que no pienses que vas a interactuar aquí como lo harías en un *foro*. Puedes hacer el [tour] para que comprendas cómo funciona este sitio.

Comment: Entiendo que ejecutas este código desde Access, te abre Word, hace lo que tiene que hacer y cierra Word pero "no vuelve" a Access como tal. En ese caso, mira [este comando](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.docmd.maximize) a ver si es lo que necesitas

Comment: Gracias @Esei, lo que esntiendes es correcto, pero el comando que propones lo probé y no hace lo esperado. tambien probé con restore y algun otro y no lo solucionan

Comment: Prueba a añadir un DoCmd.Minimize al iniciar el CommandoClick y un DoCmd.Maximize al terminar la rutina de comprobacion, eso deberia hacer que Access fuera de ventana activa

Comment: gracias @pcandido voy a probarlo, he visto que el problema se produce al usar un Surface en modo tablet, cuando se trabaja en modo pc funciona correctamente. probare lo que propones